# Why are Column based Databases faster to query?

Tags: database

I am researching on the approach to use for a new database which will be used for our new application. The amount of data won't be huge like 100 million records but will be about 10 million record before it gets archived. Will using column based approach for this much data be very useful than row based database? Why are column based database faster to query?

Comment: Since that is a teeny tiny database in relational database terms, I doubt you need anything except one of the commonly used realization row storage database. They are easier to find people qualified to maintain as the system changes.  Why reinvent the wheel? Use MySQl, or Oracle or SQL server or Postgre and you will have a lot fewer problems designing queries and hiring new staff.

Comment: @HLGEM That was the exact point I was thinking. But it seems after every 10 million records it will be archived and based on that archived data, management wants to build some other applications and this archiving process will be done every week. So eventually the data size will grow. But will it be better to use column based in that archiving database? So that was the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, the main difference between row oriented and column oriented DBs is the model they use to serialize data. Row oriented DBs store the data in each row as contiguous blocks. Column oriented DBs store the data of each *column* in contiguous blocks. Further, those blocks are typically compressed and sorted.

So, the difference in performance really depends on the type of query. Queries that use less I/O seeks will perform faster and reading from a contiguous block is a single seek. So if your query relies on aggregations or sorting on a column (or multiple columns) then a column store can perform much faster because reading all values in the column can be a single seek under optimal conditions. If your query is searching for a handful of customer records in a huge customer table based on an indexed column like a customer ID then a row store DB might actually be faster.